# Euler's Totient Function in Other Rings

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, soft-question

I'm looking for rings other than the integers on which we could define an interesting analogue of Euler's Totient function. E.g., on a Euclidean domain with norm $N$ we could let $\phi(x) = \#\left\{y\text{ coprime to }x: N(y)<N(x)\right\}$ if this number is finite, or more generally for a ring $R$ and ideal $I\subseteq R$ we could let $\phi(I)$ be the order of the units group of $R/I$. I thought it might lead to some interesting problems. My only thoughts are things like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ or polynomial rings over a finite ring.

Comment: You would definitely want to take the quotient of that set by associates, to make it more often finite (otherwise any ring with infinitely many units could never have the set be finite, which would probably be missing out).

Comment: Right, that's a good point, and also to account for the fact that the usual $\phi$ only counts positive integers.

Comment: if you define $\mu(n) = \pm 1$ for squarefree elements ($1$ the unit of your ring) and $\phi(n) = \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \frac{n}{d}$  you'll be able to define $\phi$ for any factorial ring $R$ but it's values will be on $R$ not on $\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}$ ?

Comment: Hm, it might still be interesting to compute this $\phi$ in some cases, but what are its possible interpretations?

Comment: is yours  $\sum_{d|x} \mu(x/d) |R/dR|$ ? with $R/dR$ being the set $R$ modulo $d$ and $\mu(x)$ is defined as $(-1)^k$ the number of prime factors of a squarefree $x \in R$?